# Whats wrong with this PHP code for an enquiry form?

Tags: php

I'm no expert with this but I have the code below to fill in an enquiry form & send an E-mail but its not working. Only two fields are required (the name & E-mail address) but each time I get the error message There was a problem with sending the form. Please check to ensure you have filled in all the fields.

I'm guessing it must be something in the first part but I cannot get it to work, - any ideas?

```
 <?php

 $SENT = false;
 if ($_POST && $_POST["name"] && eregi("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$", $_POST["name"]) && $_POST["email"]
 && eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $_POST
 ["email"])) {

 $recipient = "me@mydomain.com";
 $recipient = "enquiries@mydomain.com";
 $subject = "Enquiry from the Website";
 $email_header = "From: " .$_POST["email"]. " (" .$_POST["name"]. ")\r\n";
 "Reply-To: " .$_POST["email"]. "";

 // build the email
 $s = "The following contact form has been submitted:\n\n";

 $s .= "=== Customer Details =====\n";
 $s .= "Name: " .$_POST["name"]. "\n";
 $s .= "Company: " .$_POST["company"]. "\n";
 $s .= "Telephone: " .$_POST["telephone"]. "\n";
 $s .= "Email Address: " .$_POST["email"]. "\n\n";

 $s .= "=== Enquiry Information =====\n";
 $s .= trim($_POST["comments"])."\n\n";

 $s.= "Generated: " .date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

 $email = wordwrap($s, 72). "\n\n\n"; // wrap text to 72 characters

 if (@mail($recipient, $subject, $email, $email_header)) {
 $SENT = true;
 } else {
 $SENT = false;
 }
 }

 ?>


 \\Rest of HTML code here...


 <? if (!$SENT) { ?>

 <? if (!$SENT && $_POST) { ?>
 <p class="red">There was a problem with sending the form.<br />Please check to ensure you have
 filled in all the fields.</p>
 <? } ?>
 <p><b>Enquiry Form</b><br />
 <span class="red">**</span> Indicates required fields</p>

 <form name="contact" action="contact.php" method="post">
 <fieldset class="conform">
 <legend>Your Details</legend><br />
 <label for="name">Name</label>
 <input id="name" type="text" size="40" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST["name"])) ? $_POST
 ["name"] : '' ; ?>" name="name" /> <span class="red">**</span><br />
 <label for="company">Company</label>
 <input id="company" type="text" size="40" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST["company"])) ? $_POST
 ["company"] : '' ; ?>" name="company" /><br />
 <label for="telephone">Telephone</label>
 <input id="telephone" type="text" size="40" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST["telephone"])) ? 
 $_POST["telephone"] : ''; ?>" name="telephone" /><br />
 <label for="email">Email Address</label>
 <input id="email" type="text" size="40" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST["email"])) ? $_POST
 ["email"] : ''; ?>" name="email" /> <span class="red">**</span><br />
 </fieldset>

 <fieldset class="conform2">
 <legend>Further Information</legend><br />
 <textarea id="comments" name="comments" size="40" rows="8" cols="50"><?php echo(isset($_POST
 ["comments"])) ? $_POST["comments"] : '' ; ?></textarea>
 </fieldset>

 <br />
 <a href="javascript:document.contact.submit();"><img title="" height="43" alt="" 
 src="images/submit.gif" width="102" border="0" /></a>
 </form>
 </div>

 <?
 } else {
 ?>
 <p>Thank you for your enquiry. We will reply as soon as possible.</p>
 <?
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: What error message you get?

Comment: if you remove the @ from mail() you may see additional details of the error

Comment: Get rid of "@" symbol on message send function - this way you should see errors occuring on send. Or check your php error log and post some errors

Comment: Just curious, are you sure your mail application (e.g. sendmail) is working? or better put have you been able to send email successfully before?

Comment: removing the @ sign makes no difference, - I still get the same error, where can I find the php error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declaration of $email_header ends after the "\r\n". On the next line starting with "Reply-To:", it's not being appended to the $email_header.

Comment: SO what should the correct code be here then? after the $email_header?

Comment: does the Reply-To need to be appended to $email_header? - how?

Comment: Yes, you need to append to $email_header just like you do with $s below it. It should look like $email_header .= "Reply-To...";

Comment: So ive change it like this, is this correct?                                                $email_header = "From: " .$_POST["email"]. " (" .$_POST["name"]. ")\r\n".                                                               
$email_header = "Reply-To: " .$_POST["email"]. "";

Comment: Should be: `$email_header = "From: " .$_POST["email"]. " (" .$_POST["name"]. ")\r\n"; $email_header .= "Reply-To: " .$_POST["email"];`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to make any difference either, could there be some other error or code problem? Whatever I change doesn't make any difference, I stil receive the error after submitting.